# Matplotlib boxplot with groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

DataFrame

```
Year    Shows_Released  ShowType
2018    13              tvSpecial
2018    14              Short
2018    8               movie
2019    9               tvSpecial
2019    11              Short
2018    10              Documentary
2019    11              movie
2018    6               Docudrama
2019    10              Documentary
2018    7               Drama
2019    14              Docudrama
```

I need create box plots showing the Shows_Released released in 2018 vs Shows_Released in released 2019

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df=pd.read_csv('filename')
df=df[['Year', 'Shows_Released']]
grouped_df=merge.groupby('Year')
for key, item in grouped_df:
    print(grouped_df.get_group(key), "\n\n")
```

cannot figure out how to create list with all values and pass it to plt.boxplot()

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick using only matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df[['Year', 'Shows_Released']].groupby("Year").sum().reset_index()
plt.bar(df.Year, df.Shows_Released,tick_label=df.Year )
plt.savefig("test")
```

Note that I used a barplot and not a boxplot, since given your data a boxplot makes no sense, especially if you just want to sum all show types.

[image: boxplot]

Comment: thank you :) but I am required to use matplotlib

Comment: Thanks again Manuel, but I am looking for a boxplot

Comment: What would be the min, first quartile, third quartile of your boxplot ? Do you have more data than what you provided ? Does your boxplot represent the distribution of shows released per category ? A boxplot here makes no sense except if you have an answer to all of these questions. Igf you do, converting is easy, you just need to change plt.bar by plt.boxplot and adapt the data